# How to integrate similar diagam functions in my delphi application?

Tags: delphi, class, drawing, components, diagram

I would like to use some diagrams/drawings similar to the picture below in my applications especially without having to pay for any third-party components. Any idea where to start ?

[image]

Comment: I don't know any free diagram component, but you've pasted the screenshot of `SENukeX` and it has ActiveX controls, so it might be possible to use `SENukeX` in your application.

Comment: but where would I find these active X controls ?

Comment: SENukeX is not free, and is a CEO application and I don't think they have a free ActiveX with only the diagrams functions.

Comment: @Stephane, try to import it from menu `Component/Import Component`, then in `Import Component` wizard select `Import ActiveX Control` radio button and try to find `SENukeX` or something corresponding to it (or to vendor) and complete the the wizard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may look at the [JVCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/) JVDiagramShape.

You have a good example, in the **\jvcl\examples\JvDiagramShape\2. UseCaseEditor** directory created when you install the JVCL. Not as cool as your example but you may choose your own images.

[image: Use case Editor]

You may found also another example with a WebMapper, in **\jvcl\examples\JvDiagramShape\1. WebSiteScanner** :
[image: WebMapper]

Comment: Yes and, with the example a doc : Diagramming with Delphi Part 2.doc